# Showing animated SVG with external CSS style sheet with SCSS background-image

Tags: css, svg, sass, svg-animate

I have a SCSS style sheet calling an animated SVG image, the SVG image has an external CSS style sheet it references for the keyframe animations. When trying to add the SVG as a background-image the SVG will load but it is not animated.

Is it possible to have SVG animations on background-image without base64 encoding them, and if so is there a way to base64 encode the reference to the animation stylesheet?

Comment: If you use SVG as a background image it must consist of a single file. Any stylesheets must be internal to that SVG file.

Comment: This is the answer, thanks.